# Determine if $A\subset B$ and $A\subset C\Leftrightarrow A\subset (B\cup C)$ is true.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

My opinion is $A\subset B$ and $A\subset C\Rightarrow A\subset (B\cup C)$ , BUT converse is NOT true.

My proof:

($\Rightarrow$)

Suppose $A\subset B$ and $A\subset C$

Let $x\in A$

Then $ x\in B$ and $x\in C$

$\Rightarrow x\in (B\cap C)$

$\Rightarrow x\in (B\cup C)$ ($\because (B\cap C) \subset (B\cup C))$

Therefore, $A\subset B$ and $A\subset C\Rightarrow A\subset (B\cup C)$

However, I don't know how to show that the converse is NOT true. Should I find a counterexample? If so, can someone please show me how to write a counterexample to disprove the converse?

Comment: Pick $B=\left\{1,2\right\}$, $C=\left\{3\right\}$, and $A=\left\{1\right\}$. Then $A\subset(B\cup C)$ but $A$ is not a subset of $C$. Or, pick $A=\left\{1,3\right\}$. It helps to draw a Venn diagram: the picture makes it obvious that the converse is not true.

Comment: Another possibility: $A=B\ne\emptyset, C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can note that the following statement

> if $A\subset B$ *or* $A\subset C$, then $A\subset(B\cup C)$

is true and it is weaker than the statement

> if $A\subset B$ *and* $A\subset C$, then $A\subset(B\cup C)$

so you may try finding $A$ which is a subset neither of $B$ nor of $C$, but is a subset of $B\cup C$.

Hint: $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1\}$, $C={?}$