# Verify if the proposed equivalence $A \subset B \land A \subset C \iff A \subset (B \cup C)$ holds

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Only the right direction $(\Rightarrow)$ is true.

**Proof**: Suppose that $A \subset B$ and $A \subset C$ and let $x \in A$. Then clearly $x$ is also in $B$.
$A \subset B \Rightarrow x \in B \cup C$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, this shows that $A \subset (B \cup C)$.

On the other hand, the converse is not true: suppose that $A = \{5, 6, 7\}, B = \{5, 6\}$, and $C =\{7,8\}$. Then $A \subset \{5, 6, 7, 8\} = B \cup C$ but it is neither true that $A \subset B$ (since $7 \in A$ but $7 \notin B$) nor $A \subset C$
(since $5 \in A$ but $5 \notin C$).

Am I correct and is there another way simpler or is this the simplest or the only conventional one? Well, yeah I know this is just straightforward.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:general-topology]?

Comment: [the counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1849551/)

Comment: Replace union with intersection, and the equivalence would then become true.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang thanks! I guess that's called **Proof by changing the problem.** jk

Answer (score 1):

Your proof sounds good.

If you are interested in another approach, you can prove that $A\cap(B\cup C) = A$, which is equivalent to the necessary condition. That is because $X\cap Y = X$ iff $X\subseteq Y$. Indeed, one has

\begin{align*}
A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C) = A\cup A = A
\end{align*}

Hence $A\subseteq B\cup C$. That is because $A\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq C$.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @automorp15m you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Comment: Some simple math problems are hard to do mentally but are easy when expressed in terms of familiar objects. Suppose $B\cup C$ is a baseball team, where $B$ is the set of infielders and $C$ is the set of outfielders.